# iPhone if file exists issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, file-exists

From all of the examples I've seen, I do believe I'm doing this right.  Here is my code:

```
NSString* documentsPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, 
NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString* thisImage = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:image_path];
BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:thisImage];

if (fileExists){
    hotel_image = [UIImage imageNamed:image_path];
}else{
    hotel_image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"hdrHotels.jpg"];
}
```

You can assume that "image_path" equals "images/hotels/thishotel.jpg".

Now first, so that everyone understands, "hdrHotels.jpg" is in the base directory.  And "images/hotels/thishotel.jpg" are actual subdirectories (blue folers).  I've also tried using:

```
NSString* documentsPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *imagePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@",image_path];
NSString* thisImage = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:imagePath];
BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:thisImage];
```

Adding a leading "/" in front of "images/hotels/thishotel.jpg".  What is happening in both of these cases is that the "if" statement is false whether the image exists or not.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong at all.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

I changed:

```
NSString *imagePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@",image_path];
```

to:

```
NSString *imagePath = [image_path stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"images/hotels/" withString:@""];
```

But that still didn't work.

I also tried:

```
NSFileManager* fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory , NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString* documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString* myFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDir, image_path];
BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:myFilePath];
```

with no luck.

> ---------------------------------- ANSWER --------------------------------

So yeah, I finally figured it out.  I can't answer my own question since I don't have 100 rep yet, but here is the fix.

```
NSFileManager* fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSString *myFilePath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:image_path];

BOOL fileExists = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:myFilePath];

if (fileExists){
    hotel_image = [UIImage imageNamed:image_path];
}else{
    hotel_image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"hdrHotels.jpg"];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that I see this again I can finally answer it:

```
NSFileManager* fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSString *myFilePath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:image_path];

BOOL fileExists = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:myFilePath];

if (fileExists){
    hotel_image = [UIImage imageNamed:image_path];
}else{
    hotel_image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"hdrHotels.jpg"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean as "actual subdirectories (blue folders)" and "base directory" as the directories in Xcode, then all of the files will be placed in the bundle path and not in the documents directory.
Instead files in the documents directory are files that have been generated or copied or downloaded directly by the application during execution.

Comment: Well the "hotel_image = [UIImage imageNamed:image_path];" is later used to call the image. So it included the "images/hotels/" as well as the image name. But are you saying that to just check to see if the image is there, I would need to strip it down to just the image name?

Comment: if the img file is included in your project bundle, then you don't need a path on [UIImage imageNamed:]. Just the image file name. You can verify if the image is in your bundle by checking the projects Target / Build Phase / Copy Bundle Resources. If the file is in that list, you don't need a path componenet

Comment: Yes, imageNamed works on names and not on files. So it initially checks in the image cache. If not found it will search inside the app bundle. If you want to get an image from a path you must use imageWithContentsOfFile:
Consider imageNamed: as a convenient method to easily look for images that you already placed in the bundle and that you want as resources.  Besides in iOS4 you are not required to specify the image extension too (it is required in iOS<4)

Comment: So then what you two are saying is that it automatically strips "images/hotels/" out of the sting when looking for the image, which is why it finds it?

Answer (score 0):

Adding a leading / to image_path and then adding that to documentPath results in "docDir//imagePath", the filesystem treats this as "docDir/imagePath". As viggio24 suggested, first search your images in the resourceDir, then in the docDir.

Comment: I know, but I was just testing just in case.  I'm completely new to programming for the iPhone, or in any type of C language, for that matter.

Answer (score 0):

Here are four different ways (Temporary/Custom Path, Bundle Folder, Documents Folder and another form of access to Documents Folder)

```
// Temporary Path Folder (read/write files)
//
NSMutableString *tempPathFile = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithCapacity:(NSUInteger)1024];
[tempPathFile setString:[NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"export.mov"]];


// Application Folder (read-only files)
//
NSString *systemDirectoryPath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]];


// Documents Folder (read/write files)
//
NSArray *filePaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsPath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[filePaths objectAtIndex:0]];


// Another way to access Documents Folder (read/write files)
//
NSMutableString *documentsPath = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithCapacity:(NSUInteger)1024];
[documentsPath setString:[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"]];
```

Not certain of whats going on in the rest of your code but the autorelease of some of the class calls can get you so I generally alloc a mutable string for my own copy of folder paths

Comment: So with the aplication folder, if the image was part of the bundle (am I right in assuming that is what you mean?), would I need to strip the image_path variable of the "images/hotels"?

Comment: yes, you don't have to specify the path of anything included in the bundle. just the image file name is all you need and the extension is optional too.